# What does "a document in madness' exactly mean?

Tags: meaning, shakespeare

**"A document in madness"**

A line of Laertes in Hamlet.
And in my language, the word 'document' is translated as a lesson or message.

I wonder if it is a liberal translation, or 'document' actually has meaning of lesson or message.
I want to know the literal word-for-word meaning of that line.

Does it mean some kind of proof in a state of madness?

Comment: 'A "document" was an instruction, admonition, or warning. [...]' https://shakespeare-navigators.com/hamlet/Hamlet_Note_4_5_178.html

Comment: Old Brixtonian below is quite right. A *lesson* in madness is the proper way to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Etymonline, in the *early* 15th century "document" meant "a doctrine", but in the *late* 15th century,

> "teaching, instruction" (senses now obsolete), from Old
> French document (13c.) "lesson, written evidence" and directly from Latin
> documentum "example, proof, lesson," in Medieval Latin "official
> written instrument, authoritative paper," from docere "to show, teach,
> cause to know,"

So "A document in madness" means *a teaching,* or *a lesson,* on madness."

Perhaps we would say "a manual on madness."

Answer (score 0):

The word *document* back then probably carried with it the archaic definition which was *evidence* or *proof*.

See definition #4 here https://www.dictionary.com/browse/document